# Wrong results for aritmetic operations with float values & casting - big diffrence, I guess it's not a case of inncacurate values (429497)?

Tags: c++, floating-point

I have some code:

```
float distance = pos + (screenSpeed * (float)(lastUpdateTimeMS - actualTimeMS));
```

This line should calculate the distance the character will move (the delta of position, from last check to actual time). But I've discovered it gives ridiculous results, e.g. for:

```
screenSpeed = 0.0001f;
lastUpdateTimeMS = 106;
actualTimeMS = 106;
```

I get `429497` and the following parts of my formula gives me:

```
(float)(lastUpdateTimeMS - actualTimeMS) = 4.29497e+009
(screenSpeed * (float)(lastUpdateTimeMS - actualTimeMS)) = 429497
```

And I get that magic `429497` (which is not the float/int range's end or anything familiar to me) for other arguments (`screenSpeed` is always `0.0001f`, the `lastUpdateTimeMS` and `actualTimeMS` are different - sometimes they are equal, sometimes not).

Both the `lastUpdateTimeMS` and `actualTimeMS` are of `unsigned` type (`int`).

I am aware of that floating point numbers have some inaccurate, but with such a big differences I don't understand it.

I am working on x64 machine, with Visual Studio C++ 2013 (I build for x32 anyway), my project include some libraries (maybe there are some build options that I should be aware of or, when set differently in `.lib` and my code, results with such problems)?

Comment: Can you add which line you use to print?

Comment: @AerofoilKite I use 3-rd partly library with some LOG method that prints to file - it's a long piece of code, so it wouldn't be nice to copy it here :/ But it has always worked for me and I'm 99.99% sure that the values in log file are exactly the same as in the code - also, I see the result in VS debugger and on screen - with the character moving with the speed of light ;p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am aware of that floating point numbers have some inaccurate, but with such a big differences I don't understand it.

First, the floating-point inaccuracy is proportional to the values you manipulate.

Second, you are likely to have an overflow in the subtraction of the two unsigned 32-bit values in your computation `lastUpdateTimeMS - actualTimeMS`, giving a result near 2<sup>32</sup>. This value is then converted to `float` and multiplied by `0.0001f`, producing `429497`.

In other words, your problem is that `actualTimeMS` is slightly larger than `lastUpdateTimeMS`. Also if the names of the variables can be trusted, shouldn't the subtraction be the other way round?

> And I get that magic 429497 (which is not the float/int range's end or anything familiar to me)

It is exactly 2<sup>32</sup> * 0.0001.

Comment: `lastUpdateTimeMS - actualTimeMS` should produce 0. why near 2^32.? Can you explain?

Comment: @AerofoilKite made a question I wanted to ask too ;) And how can I overcome the problem with subtraction of my 32-bits unsigned values? I mean, without changing their types and making additional assumption that the check will be called with lower frequency (so the values would be more different and never the same)?

Comment: @PolGraphic What is supposed to happen when `actualTimeMS` is larger than `lastUpdateTimeMS`? I think you may want to compute a signed result. For this, you need to convert to a signed type before the subtraction. One signed type you can convert to is the integer type `long long`, which is at least 64-bit wide and can hold all the values of `unsigned int`. Since you are going to compute with `float` anyway, you can also convert to `float`, which is signed, but this may lose a lot of precision. The subtraction of two nearby large floating-point values is known as “catastrophic cancellation”.

Comment: @AerofoilKite When `unsigned int` is 32-bit, `12U - 13U` produces 2^32-1, as well as `1234U - 1235U`. What's to explain? This is the behavior of overflow for unsigned integer types in C. It works this way because the C standard says so.

Comment: @PolGraphic Perhaps you should make sure they have type `unsigned int` and print them with `printf("%u")` to be sure that they both contain 106.

Comment: @PascalCuoq, `106U - 106U = `?

Comment: @AerofoilKite Yes, that is supposed to be zero. Either there is something wrong with the printing function or the way it is invoked, or the compiler produces wrong code.

Comment: Now explain this.. His `lastUpdateTimeMS=106` and `actualTimeMS=106` .. Why `lastUpdateTimeMS - actualTimeMS`, giving a result near `2^32` .. ? You told this

Answer (score 0):

(i) You seem to have your variables the wrong way round: surely it should be `actualTimeMS - lastUpdateTimeMS`?

(ii) `unsigned - unsigned` is `unsigned`, which you don't want. Instead of casting to `float`, which is done automatically anyway (to `double`, in fact), you should cast to `int` to make it signed.

(iii) Your diagnostics are faulty. `106U - 106U` is zero, so `screenSpeed * (float)(lastUpdateTimeMS - actualTimeMS)` is zero too. Perhaps those variables are being updated in another thread (in which case you have a whole new set of problems to solve)? Perhaps the problem is that `pos` variable?

Comment: Converting to `int` before the subtraction means there can be a signed arithmetic overflow in the subtraction (which is undefined behavior) if `actualTimeMS` is 2^31-1 and `lastUpdateTimeMS` is `lastUpdateTimeMS`. If you want a signed result, it is better to convert the unsigned result of the subtraction to signed (assuming 2's complement, which most architectures use).

Comment: @PascalCuoq: I meant simply replacing the `(float)` cast with an `(int)` cast in the same place. So I think we agree.